# buildschema from graphql throws 'TypeError: nodes.flatMap is not a function'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql-js, express-graphql

Am using node version 10.24.0.

But when I try the example from the official site.

```
const graphql = require('graphql');

const schema = graphql.buildSchema(`
    type Query {
    hello: String
}`);
```

I get the following error.

```
TypeError: nodes.flatMap is not a function
```

Am using grapql@16.5.0

On the graphql official page, it says

`Before getting started, you should have Node v6 installed, although the examples should mostly work in previous versions of Node as well.`

So What can I do to get graphql to work here?